# Artefacts when exporting model with holes to keyshot

Tags: modifiers, uv

First picture is object when imported to keyshot. It should have hole in the middle.
[image]

Attached UVs with blender model on second picture. What might be the problem?
[image]

Comment: Are you using a boolean modifier in blender?

Comment: Yes
First time I used Bool tool and it was the same, then I tried boolean modifier and it remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***Solution to this problem:***

1. Select all inner edges and bevel them. *Dont forget that you should bevel all of which I highlighted with pink,red and blue to avoid dissapointments in texture and strange reflections when importing to keyshot*
   [image]
2. Bevel all outer edges, including sides, top and bottom edges highlighted with PINK, dont worry about ORANGE ones, we dont need them.
   [image]
3. This step is important because Keyshot doesn't like Ngons and Quads, so always do this step.
   [image]
4. UV unwrap with smart UV project
   [image]
5. Shade smooth an object and turn on autosmooth
   [image]
   [image]
6. And then you should end up with quality model without any strange artefacts or reflections ready for adding texture in Keyshot.

[image]

*Hope this helps someone in the future!*